# Spring JPA is not filling data from MySQL database

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to populate my JpaRepository with data from a MySQL database. The `List<AccountEntity> findAll()` method is not working, however it does work when I force it to use a native query with `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Account", nativeQuery = true)`. Can anyone help me find a reason as to why the JpaRepository is not being populated with data from MySQL on launch of the application? Let me know if you require more source code.

**AccountController.java**

```
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<AccountEntity> getAllAccounts() {
        return accountService.findAllAccounts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAccountById/{id}")
    public AccountEntity getAccountById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return accountService.findAccountById(id);
    }
}
```

**AccountRepository.java**

```
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountEntity, Integer> {
    AccountEntity findById(int id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Account", nativeQuery = true) // the line giving problems
    List<AccountEntity> findAll();
}
```

**AccountService.java**

```
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AccountService {
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public List<AccountEntity> findAllAccounts() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public AccountEntity findAccountById(int id) {
        return accountRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Added** `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/inventory
spring.datasource.username=///////
spring.datasource.password=///////
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Comment: You should also provide the application.properties that you have concerning database connectivity

Comment: Try this spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: check the SQL issued from your Find all query and compare it to your native query. I would guess you have a relationship you aren't showing in the entity that is eager and your JPA provider (hibernate?) is using an inner fetch join to load it in the same query and this is causing no results to be found. Make this relationship lazy and/or change it so it is optional (if hibernate) to ensure it fetched using an outer join instead. If you need more of an explanation, you'll need to show your entities (and the SQL issued)

Comment: @Chris this sounds most plausible, I will try to change it and see what results I get.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

I think the findAll() and findById() methods is already implemented for you through the JPA Data repository so there is no need to create it. Unless you want to override it.

##### Updated AccountRepository.java

```
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountEntity, Integer> {
  
}
```

**The reset of the classes remain the same.**
Check Spring Data Documentation : (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)!

Comment: Sadly this did not work, this command is put in the console when I try to access the /all endpoint. `Hibernate: select a1_0.account_id,a1_0.address,a1_0.first_name,a1_0.last_name,a1_0.level_id,a1_0.passhash,a1_0.username from account_entity a1_0`